# How to remove header bar in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to MVVMCross and trying to build my first app.

I want to remove header bar, Can I remove header bar in MVVMCross (The bar inside Red rectangle)?

[image: Remove header bar]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered how to fix. Just use Theme in activity as following:

```
[Activity(Label = "View for MainMenu", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar")]
public class MainMenuView : MvxPreferenceActivity<MainMenuViewModel>
{
}
```